# Entire file system permissions were changed on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: filesystem, hadoop

I'm running hadoop in my machine with hduser. When I was trying to user 'put' and 'get' commands it was throwing that "permission denied".

```
hduser@salmon-son-of-god:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.5/bin$ hadoop fs -get /user/mySQL\ commands /home/salmon/Desktop/
18/03/21 15:43:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
get: /home/salmon/Desktop/mySQL commands._COPYING_ (Permission denied)
```

So I have mistakenly changed the file system ownership in my machine. When tried to deal with my files it is throwing the error like "Permission denied".

```
hduser@salmon-son-of-god:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.5/bin$ ls -l /home/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 23 salmon sudo 4096 Mar 21 15:07 hduser
drwxr-xr-x 18 salmon sudo 4096 Mar  7 12:17 krishna
drwxrwxrwx 30 salmon sudo 4096 Mar 21 16:01 salmon
```

when I changed the permissions on home directory to one user salmon, hadoop wasn't able to copy files to local file system. If I change permission to hduser local files were not accessed by salmon user.

When I check for same issue in Stack Overflow the people answered that you need to back up the file system and reinstall OS again.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can try single user mode ( Recovery mode ) and chown everything back to root. But there can be a lot of problems after that.

Comment: You can reset /home to defaults: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dmrcErrors but if you changed /  (root), you cannot really change settings back. Many are owned by root, but many others are not, so some things just will not work. Reinstall is often best alternative. User settings should be salmon salmon, not salmon sudo. try:`sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/$USER`.